# Why is Android 11 mandating INTENT_ACTION_TTS_SERVICE?

Tags: android, android-11, android-tts

Android [developers reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech) states that:

Apps targeting Android 11 that use text-to-speech should declare TextToSpeech.Engine.INTENT_ACTION_TTS_SERVICE in the queries elements of their manifest:

```
 <queries>
   ...
  <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.TTS_SERVICE" />
  </intent>
 </queries>
```

I have my app working flawlessly with TextToSpeech on Android 11 and 13 without this clause in the manifest, so the obvious question is *"why?"*:

1. Why is this requirement?
2. What would break if this requirement is not implemented?
3. What would the app be gaining if I implement this requirement?

Comment: "I have my app working flawlessly with TextToSpeech on Android 11 and 13 without this clause in the manifest" -- what is your app's `targetSdk` or `targetSdkVersion` value in the module's `build.gradle`? "Why is this requirement?" -- apparently, something about implementing TTS requires code to try finding `TTS_SERVICE` implementations via `PackageManager`, and that in turn requires this `<queries>` element once your `targetSdkVersion` value reaches 30 or higher.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you. So, it is PackageManager that requires it. My `build.gradle` has  `targetSdkVersion 33` and `minSdkVersion 26`. Please post as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<queries>` element adds items to the allowlist for package visibility. [Package visibility](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility) constrains what `PackageManager` will return to your app when you try finding out information about other installed apps. This not only affects direct calls to `PackageManager` but other framework methods that in turn use `PackageManager` in your app's process.

I have not worked with TTS, but apparently something in TTS needs to use `PackageManager` to find `TTS_SERVICE` implementations. At least, that is the only justification that I can see for those instructions.

> What would break if this requirement is not implemented?

Since you are not breaking now, my best guess is that you might not be able to use third-party TTS engines that tie into this framework. Even with the package visibility restrictions, `PackageManager` will return information about many pre-installed apps — the restriction mostly affects user-installed apps.

FWIW, I cover package visibility in Android 11 in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/R/pages/chap-package-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/R).